# how to write largest circle inscribed inside a triangle as an optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

can someone show me how to write this problem as a convex optimization problem.Find the largest disk that can be bounded by $X \geq 0$ , $Y \geq0$ and $X+2Y\leq1$.

My institution is to cast to problem using supporting hyperplane theorem , but I don't know how to write the equation .

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Geez, I totally forgot that Section 4.3.1 of Boyd & Vandenberghe's book [Convex Optimization](http://stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/) shows how to compute the *Chebyshev center* of a polyhedron described by inequalities. The Chebyshev center *is* the center of the largest inscribed circle of the polygon; and the model that computes it gives the radius as well.

I could have skipped all of this development and gone right to the simplified circle case below. Sorry about that. I will leave it in for posterity and in case others are interested. But you can go right to Section 4.3.1 of the book, *or* the corresponding example in the CVX example library, to see this in action.

---

It is well known that the task of inscribing an ellipsoid with the largest possible volume in a polyhedron described by linear inequalities
$$a_i^T x \leq b_i, \quad i=1,2,\dots, n$$
is a convex program. Section 8.4.1 of Boyd & Vandenberghe's book [Convex Optimization](http://stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/) describes just how to do this. The model looks like this:
\begin{array}{ll}
    \text{maximize}_{B,d} & \log\det B \\
    \text{subject to} & \| B a_i \| + a_i^T d \leq b_i, ~i=1,2,\dots, m
\end{array}
The variables are a symmetric, positive definite matrix $B$ and a vector $d$.  (The positive definiteness of $B$ is implicitly constrained by the objective function, so you do not need to specify it as a constraint.)

The actual volume of the ellipse is $\det B$, but that's not concave. So $\log\det B$ is chosen instead because it *is* concave and it yields the same result. You can also use $(\det B)^{1/n}$, which is not only concave but SDP-representable as well, so more solvers are likely to be able to handle it.

The example in that section is included in the [CVX example library](http://cvxr.com/cvx/examples), using the $(\det B)^{1/n}$ alternative. 
It looks like this:

```
cvx_begin
    variable B(n,n) symmetric
    variable d(n)
    maximize( det_rootn( B ) )
    subject to
       for i = 1:m
           norm( B*A(i,:)', 2 ) + A(i,:)*d <= b(i);
       end
cvx_end
```

Now of course, you don't want an ellipse, you want a circle. One way to look at it is that you're solving the same problem as before, only you are fixing the relative shape of $B$ by ensuring that $B=\beta I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix. You could just add $B=\beta I$ as a constraint into the above model, with $\beta$ as an additional variable. But a little more care lets us simplify the objective considerably, and the result is a *linear* program:
\begin{array}{ll}
    \text{maximize}_{\beta,d} & \beta \\
    \text{subject to} & \beta \| a_i \| + a_i^T d \leq b_i, ~i=1,2,\dots, m
\end{array}

Here is the corresponding CVX model:

```
cvx_begin
    variable beta
    variable d(n)
    maximize( beta )
    subject to
       for i = 1:m
           beta * norm( A(i,:)', 2 ) + A(i,:)*d <= b(i);
       end
cvx_end
```

Comment: Sure. For your specific model, it becomes this:\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & Z \\ \text{subject to} & X \geq Z \\ & Y \geq Z \\ & X + 2Y + \sqrt{5} Z \leq 1 \end{array}$(X,Y)$ will be the center, and $Z$ will be the radius.